# Anchor to an id that added using js only after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a project Im working on I have a link with href:

```
<a href="#ID123"> Link </a>
```

This id does not exist in the page. After clicking this link - a JS function adds a div with this ID.

```
<div id="ID123"> some text </div>
```

and also the anchor spears on the url **[www.web.com/#ID123](http://www.web.com/#ID123)**

I want to preform an anchor action right after the div added.
I tried a lot of things but non of them really works.

I'd be happy for some help using only JavaScript and not any other library.

thx.

Comment: Care to share the JavaScript code?

Comment: after the anchor is added, try `location.href='#ID123'`

Comment: I tried but its not working :( 
I tried: `window.scrollTo();` and `id.scrollIntoView();` as well

Comment: Does it add the anchor tag after clicking, and you want the page to go to that ID after that?